# Plotting scikit-learn confusion matrix returns no values in the last class

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification, confusion-matrix, convolutional-neural-network

I am attempting to create a confusion matrix using `Scikit-Learn` for a multiclass classification CNN, and it works well except for the fact that it does not provide values for the last class (i.e. all of them are zero), as illustrated in the image below:

[image]

Here is the function that I used to generate the confusion matrix and plot:

```
# Function to Calculate Ensemble Confusion Matrix for Given Dataset
    def getConfusionMatrix(self, y_true, y_pred, speaker_labels, title):
        
        # Calculate Confusion Matrix
        cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
        
        print(cm)
        
        # Instantiate Plot Variables
        cmap = plt.cm.Blues # Color map for confusion matrix
        title = title # Plot title
        ticks = np.arange(len(speaker_labels)+1)
        fmt = 'd' # Data format
        thresh = cm.max()/2. # Treshold
        
        # Plot Confusion Matrix
        plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
        plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
        plt.title(title)
        plt.colorbar()
        plt.xticks(ticks, speaker_labels, rotation=45)
        plt.yticks(ticks, speaker_labels)
        
        for (i, j) in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
            plt.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt),
                     color='white' if cm[i, j] > thresh else 'black')
        
        plt.ylabel('True Label')
        plt.xlabel('Predicted Label')
```

How can I ensure that the confusion matrix calculates TP/FP/TN/FN for the final class (i.e. `ARA NORM` in the image)? Is this possibly an issue with input into the confusion_matrix() function?

Comment: Do you know for certain that you have some observations in the ARA NORM class? And some predictions in the ARA NORM class?

Comment: @NickKoprowicz yes the ARA NORM class should contain approximately 20 predictions/observations. I ran the same code with a different dataset containing the ARA NORM class, but a different class was the last one. With that dataset, there were 20 predictions in ARA NORM, but zero in the last one.